# image src attribute does not display locally-stored image

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have images stored as png files on the local server and only the filename gets saved to the DB. When rendering images to the client I combine the relative path of the image with the filename from the db as pass it in like so:

```
<img src='../../public/avatar-pictures/3fVZNShyQRAtBbipvzVrDwDD.png'/>
```

But it doesn't work. As a last attempt of desperation, I even moved the png file itself to the root directory of the client script and it still produced nothing.

what is causing this issue?

Comment: Do you have file permissions on that script and the directories above it?
`../` can easily lead to a directory traversal attack, so some web servers are blocking access. Check the error logs there as well.
Also, you can check the network tab of the browser DevTools to investigate it more.
By updating the DOM in the Inspector tab, you can trigger additional requests and figure out the right path.

Comment: if your web root is `public`, i.e `/` then no amount of `../` will traverse into that folder. Place your files in a accessible location, then use a relative path to them. Like `./avatar-pictures/3fVZNShyQRAtBbipvzVrDwDD.png`

Comment: Look at this one : https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Either log the incoming request URL on  your server or look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger and see exactly what URL the browser is requesting.  That will hopefully shed some light on why the server isn't serving it for you.  A node.js server does not serve ANY files by default.  So, unless you have specific routes in your web server that find these images on the server's hard drive and send them back to the client when requested, nothing will be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, node.js and Express do not serve any files.  So, you can't give the browser a path to some location on your server's hard drive and expect the web server to send the files.  It does not do that (unlike what people familiar with Apache might expect).

You will need a route on your server that points to the public directory.  There are several ways to do it, but here's one:

```
<img src='/public/avatar-pictures/3fVZNShyQRAtBbipvzVrDwDD.png'/>
```

Then, on your server, you would use the `express.static()` middleware to create a route that looks for URLs starting with `/public` and will serve files from the public directory on your hard drive that match the path of the URL:

```
app.use("/public", express.static("../../public"));
```

The path you pass to `express.static()` needs to point to the public directory on your local hard drive.  You don't disclose your local file structure so I can't tell you exactly what that should be.  The example above will be relative to the current working directory when your program was started.  It is perhaps more common to build the path yourself from the module directory.  So, if the `public` directory is two levels above your module directory, you might do this:

```
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../public")));
```

And, then it's wired more specifically to be relative to your module's directory and not dependent upon the current working directory which can be changed by code or by how your program is launched.

You can, of course, also use a fully qualified path:

```
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join("/someVol/users/me/myProject/public")));
```

---

Keep in mind that the `express.static()` middleware opens up the entire directory tree that you point it at for public access so you have to make absolutely sure that only public things are in there.  By default, `express.static()` does not permit `..` in the paths so a request can't get out of the directory you specify.

Comment: I already have a route which points to the public directory like so: ```router.use('/players/avatars', express.static(path.PUBLIC.AVATAR_PICTURES))```
Correct me if I'm wrong but I need to call this route when someone navigates to the main page which is under ```router.get('/')```. So the question is how can I call or invoke ```router.use('/players/avatars')``` within the GET route? Does that question make sense?

Comment: Adding to the comment above, I tried: ```<img src='/players/avatars'{{ this.avatar }} width="150" height="150"/>``` and it still produces nothing

Comment: One more clarification: ```router.get('/')``` is the main page where all user info is displayed including the avatars

Comment: @Igor - No.  You almost never call routes conditionally like that.  You are either serving pages from the public directory or you aren't.  You don't do it only sometimes.  And you would never put something like `router.use(...)` inside another route.  That would just build up duplicate route handlers every time the route was hit.

Comment: @Igor - So, your route: `router.use('/players/avatars', express.static(path.PUBLIC.AVATAR_PICTURES))` is NOT configured to handle the URL you started all this with: `/public/avatar-pictures/3fVZNShyQRAtBbipvzVrDwDD.png` so you're not serving that URL.  The structure I offered will serve that URL.  You can point more than one `express.static()` middleware at the same public directory if you really want to, but a more well thought through design would structure the URLs so they can all be served with one `express.static()` route pointing at that public directory.

Comment: @Igor - It appears you're still trying to think of URLs as "belonging" to a page. That isn't how web servers work.  A public URL is just a resource on your web server.  It's not associated with a particular page.  Any page can request that URL.  You configure a route on your server that handles that URL no matter who requests it.  You don't add routes only when a certain page is being displayed.  You pre-configure all the routes that will be needed by all the pages.  You can write dynamic routes, but that isn't what's going on here or what is needed here.

Comment: Just solved this issue based on your original comment. my profile doesn't have enough points to upvote your answer so please accept my thank you here

Comment: @Igor - Cool, glad you got it solved.  With any level of points, you can "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That indicates to the community that your question has been answered and also earns you a few points for following the proper procedure here.